# SSL certificate verification fails

Tags: curl, ssl, libcurl, docusignapi

In going through the API tutorials, I'm getting the following error: "SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK."

The CA certificate is not in my build of libcurl. Is there anyway I can get it from DocuSign in PEM format?

Answer (score 0):

DocuSign does not create or provide SSL Certificates, the platform simply uses them where needed.  It's the client's responsibility to handle certs.

To resolve I think you'll need to get a proper certificate from whomever your cert authority is, however if you are testing in DEMO (i.e. demo.docusign.net) I believe you can test with https (port 443) OR http (port 80).  So you might be able to get around this by testing with http://demo.docusign.net, give it a try...